# Schedule Control color appointments C#

Tags: c#, sql, winforms, calendar, connection

i added a schedule control to a WinForm application and connected it to a SQL database where i stored the appointment dates. What is than displayed on the schedule control is two sets of dates namely "Working & NonWorking". So to distinguish between the two different days i assigned each with a different color. When i run the application the two sets of dates are displayed with their different colors but the moment i scroll or select something on the schedule control the colors seem to vanish which defeats the purpose of the application because without the color all that is left is appointments with dates and times but no color. So basically i need a way to keep the color after pressing or scrolling in order to tell what is what.

```
    string CalendarCode = "";
    const int Working = 0;
    const int NonWorking = 1;
    static Color lbWorking = new Color();
    static Color lbNonWorking = new Color();


    AppointmentLabel lbWorkingDay;
    AppointmentLabel lbNonWorkingDay;
    public void Calendardate()
    {


        lbWorking = Color.SkyBlue;
        lbNonWorking = Color.LightPink;
        lbWorkingDay = new AppointmentLabel(lbWorking, "Working Day", "WorkingDay");
        lbNonWorkingDay = new AppointmentLabel(lbNonWorking, "Non Working Day", "&NonWorkingDay");

        schedulerStorage1.Appointments.Labels.Clear();
        schedulerStorage1.Appointments.Labels.Add(lbWorkingDay);
        schedulerStorage1.Appointments.Labels.Add(lbNonWorkingDay);

    }
```